# Can't add listeners to CalendarView events

Tags: java, android

There is the following code:

```
    final CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView)layout.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarView.setClickable(true);
    calendarView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    });
    calendarView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Touch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

    });
    calendarView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

    });
```

I haven't got any messages yet. I need to set listeners for click by Date. I know about OnDateChangeListener, but it will work only if user changes the date, but if user clicks by the same date I haven't got any messages. Please tell me, how can I set listeners for click by dates. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The native Calendar is crappy IMO. It seems like clicking on any of the date won't fire any events at all. However the onClick and onLongClick event will be fired if you click near the border of the calendar.